# Html float list with sub lists proper alignment

Tags: html, css, html-lists

As you can see at the snippet below, i have an UL element with some li elements. Some of the li elements have children that is a nested UL. Think that this is going to be a main menu. I choose to split the menu in three (3) columns setting the width of the li to 33%.

**Note that all the ul and li are created dynamically through code. So i don't know in advanced the length of each nested ul.**

As you can see running the snippet we get the following:
[screenshot of snippet result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2YOI.png)

I am trying to find a way to eliminate the "gaps" due to nested ul length. For example the Item 11 should be higher just below at the end of Item 4 and its children.

Is it possible something like that ?

```css
.panel {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em;
 width: auto;
}

ul.navigator li {
 float: left;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
 position: relative;
 width: 33%;
}

ul.navigator li a {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.children-menu li {
 padding-left: 1em;
 float: none;
}

ul.children-menu li a {
 color: #333;
 font-size: 1em;
}

/**************** RESET.css ************************/

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<header>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <body>
    <div class="panel">
      <ul class="navigator">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
          <ul class="children-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Children 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Item 7</a>
          <ul class="children-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Children 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 6</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 7</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 8</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Item 8</a>
          <ul class="children-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Children 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 6</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 9</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 10</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 11</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 12</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 13</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Item 14</a>
          <ul class="children-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Children 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Children 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 15</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 16</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You will need javascript for that sort of layout, search for masonry or waterfall js etc.